# Importing a File with Dynamic Columns

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssis, etl, flat-file

I am new to SSIS and C#. In SQL Server 2008 I am importing data from a .csv file. Now I have the columns dynamic. They can be around 22 columns(some times more or less). I created a staging table with 25 columns and import data into it. In essence each flat file that I import has different number of columns. They are all properly formatted only. My task is to import all the rows from a .csv flat file including the headers. I want to put this in a job so I can import multiple files into the table daily.

So inside a for each loop I have a data flow task within which I have a script component. I came up(research online) with the C# code below but I get error:

**Index was outside the bounds of the array.**

I tried to find the cause using MessageBox and I found it is reading the first line and the index is going outside the bounds of the array after the first line.

1.) I need your help with fixing the code

2.) My File1Conn is the flat file connection instead I want to read it directly from a variable **User::FileName** that my foreach loop keeps updating. Please help with modifying the code below.

**Thanks in advance.**

This is my flat file:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B418ObdiVnEIRnlsZFdwYTRfTFU/view?usp=sharing

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.Wrapper;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Wrapper;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;

[Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.SSISScriptComponentEntryPointAttribute]
public class ScriptMain : UserComponent

{
 private StreamReader SR;
 private string File1;

public override void AcquireConnections(object Transaction)
{
    // Get the connection for File1
    IDTSConnectionManager100 CM = this.Connections.File1Conn;
    File1 = (string)CM.AcquireConnection(null);
}

public override void PreExecute()
{
    base.PreExecute();
    SR = new StreamReader(File1);
}

public override void PostExecute()
{
    base.PostExecute();
    SR.Close();
}

public override void CreateNewOutputRows()
{
    // Declare variables
    string nextLine;
    string[] columns;
    char[] delimiters;
    int Col4Count;
    String[] Col4Value = new string[50];

    // Set the delimiter
    delimiters = ";".ToCharArray();

    // Read the first line (header)
    nextLine = SR.ReadLine();

    // Split the line into columns
    columns = nextLine.Split(delimiters);

    // Find out how many Col3 there are in the file
    Col4Count = columns.Length - 3;
    //MessageBox.Show(Col4Count.ToString());

    // Read the second line and loop until the end of the file
    nextLine = SR.ReadLine();

    while (nextLine != null)
    {

        // Split the line into columns
        columns = nextLine.Split(delimiters);
        {
            // Add a row
            File1OutputBuffer.AddRow();


            // Set the values of the Script Component output according to the file content
            File1OutputBuffer.SampleID = columns[0];
            File1OutputBuffer.RepNumber = columns[1];
            File1OutputBuffer.Product = columns[2];
            File1OutputBuffer.Col1 = columns[3];
            File1OutputBuffer.Col2 = columns[4];
            File1OutputBuffer.Col3 = columns[5];
            File1OutputBuffer.Col4 = columns[6];
            File1OutputBuffer.Col5 = columns[7];
            File1OutputBuffer.Col6 = columns[8];
            File1OutputBuffer.Col7 = columns[9];
            File1OutputBuffer.Col8 = columns[10];
            File1OutputBuffer.Col9 = columns[11];
            File1OutputBuffer.Col10 = columns[12];
            File1OutputBuffer.Col11 = columns[13];
            File1OutputBuffer.Col12 = columns[14];
            File1OutputBuffer.Col13 = columns[15];
            File1OutputBuffer.Col14 = columns[16];
            File1OutputBuffer.Col15 = columns[17];
            File1OutputBuffer.Col16 = columns[18];


        }

        // Read the next line
        nextLine = SR.ReadLine();

    }
}

}
```

Comment: Instead of trying to send rows to an output buffer, why don't you just send them to their ultimate destination all within the script?   Another option is BiML.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned the file has dynamic amount of columns, in your script component you need to count number of columns by delimiters, then redirect to different outputs.

For your 2nd question, you can assign your variable to the flat file connection manager connection string property. Then you can read the variable value in your script directly.

Except for script component, you can create a "one column" flat file source by using a dummy delimiter, then in the data flow task, you can read amount of columns into a variable, conditional split the data flow, redirect the outputs into different destinations. An example can be found at http://sqlcodespace.blogspot.com.au/2015/03/ssis-design-pattern-handling-flat-file.html

Comment: Both your solutions are already implemented in the code. My have multiple flat files with different number of columns. In your example your flat file has 3 columns which is fixed.Each flat file has different number of columns. number of columns

Comment: As far as I know, in script component amount of output columns cannot be changed during run time. Therefore in your case you can think of: (a) third party component, or write a custom data flow component (b) use a for each loop and a script component at control flow level, in the script component read file and write into destination and (c) like I suggested treat variable column files as "one column" files, then by using derived column (to count actual column) and conditional split components, you can navigate outputs into multi destinations